# Chained React Query mutations create an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to chain two mutations with custom hooks and mutateAsync but I'm getting the React error saying that there are too many re-renders and it targets the call of the two mutations.

Here's my code with my call of the two custom hooks (they are normally in two different files):

```
const {
    mutateAsync: mutateTenant,
    isError: tenantIsError,
    error: tenantError,
  } = useCreateTenant(router);
  const {
    data: customerId,
    mutateAsync: mutateCustomer,
    isSuccess,
    isError: customerIsError,
    error: customerError,
  } = useCreateCustomer();

  if (isSuccess) {
    setState({ ...state, customerId });
  }

  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    await mutateCustomer(values);
    await mutateTenant(values);
  };
```

Here are the content of my two custom hooks:

```
export const useCreateCustomer = () => {
  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (values) => createCustomer(values),
  });
  return mutation;
};

export const useCreateTenant = (router: NextRouter) => {
  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (values) => createTenant(values),
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      successToast(data.message);
      router.push('/register/plan');
    },
  });
  return mutation;
};
```

I've seen multiple solutions like chaining the calls in a mutationFn or calling the second function in the `onSuccess` callback of the first function. Still, I want to use the solution with the `mutateAsync` because I can keep my two mutations separated in different files.
I don't really understand why I'm getting this error because the mutations are actually working (the data is sent to the database and the `router.push` function is working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loop is caused by the line `setState({ ...state, customerId });`.

It will update the state for each render, which will in turn cause a new render.

To solve this, place the if-statement in a `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (isSuccess) {
    setState({ ...state, customerId });
  }
}, [isSuccess, customerId]);
```

Or better yet, remove `customerId` from the state and use `customerId` directly instead.